# How do I remove required fields (or a required attribute) from customer profile in Drupal Commerce?

Tags: 7, commerce

I only need customer to fill in name, phone and MAYBE address. Is it doable in Commerce?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only data required for the commerce profile is defined by the fields you attach to it. By default that is the addressfield. You make the field required or not required, which will result in some fields being required or not required.

You have two ways of solving this. You can either change the behavior of the address field by creating a plugin (code).

Or you can choose to only store the address in the address field and make it options and create a separate field for name that you can make required.